# google api / javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I wrote an application that creates a circle on a map, if you run the code it works, but i'm wondering why it only works when there are two separate script tags and the circle is in some sort of a loop because when I uncheck the box and recheck it, it keeps creating circles.

```
At certain ppb first warning:
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onchange="makeCircle()">

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 27.804065,
      lng: -97.423481
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

}
</script>
<script>

  function makeCircle() {
    new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#3399CC',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#3399CC',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: {
        lat: 27.82222,
        lng: -97.42612
      },
      radius: 1500
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle or in a stacksnippet that shows this code running in a loop?

Comment: tried putting it on jsfiddle but wasn't working, I could send you the entire code though @Turnip